# Can we test whether a density is bounded away from $0$ at a point given sample data?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with unknown support $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and unknown density $f$. Given a finite iid sample $D$, is there a test to check whether the density $f$ is bounded away from $0$ at a particular point in $\mathbb{R} \supseteq S$?

I feel like this is something not testable, since if you observe a point in the sample, you know the density at that point is positive; but if you don't observe a particular point, then there's no way to tell. Existing kernel methods to approximate the density use smoothing so even if the true density is $0$ but continuous (or discontinuous but the jump is very small) at a particular point, it will get smoothed out by nearby observations.

I'm not sure if this is the right intuition. Searched online and couldn't find any relevant work/statistical tests.

Comment: Here's an example. Consider the uniform distribution $D = U[a, 1]$. Put a prior on $a$. Next, let $X_1, \ldots, X_N \sim D$ be your iid samples. Compute the posterior $f(a | X_1, \ldots, X_N)$. Now you can answer, what is the probability that $a > 0$ conditional on the data?

Comment: @parsiad Hi there - thanks for the comment! I see what you're saying. But in this case we know the true DGP is from uniform. What would happen in the general case then?

Comment: @parsiad I think you are misinterpreting OP's question. OP is asking about how to test whether $f(x_0) > 0$ for a given $x_0$. You seem to be answering a different question regarding the lower bound of the support of the density, i.e. $\inf \{x : f(x) > 0\}$.

Comment: @angryavian Yes you're right, though here it happens that if we know the DGP is from uniform and we know the upper bound of the support, we can figure out on what interval is the density bounded away from $0$ by figuring out the lower bound of the support. And yes I'm interested in the more general case where we're just given a random iid sample without any additional information on what the DGP is.

Comment: @angryavian: Thanks for catching that! For some reason my brain read it as "support is bounded away from zero".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in general no. As you mention, discontinuities can make this impossible without further assumptions. However, this does become possible if you are willing to make some (smoothness) assumptions on $f$.

Note that such a requirement on $f$ is necessary to do any kind of inference about $f$ at a particular point, because (Lebesgue) densities are not unique. They are only unique up to (Lebesgue) null sets, and a singleton is a null set.

If you are willing to assume that $f$ is twice differentiable, for example, then there are ways to perform an asymptotic t-test for the value $f(x_0)$ for a particular point $x_0$. The way to calculate the standard error depends on your chosen estimator.